# Problem publishing an MVC app on IIS6

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, model-view-controller, iis-6

I have a small MVC app that works locally, but when I publish it to the server (running IIS6), all the links get messed up.

For example, a typical link when running locally would be:

```
http://localhost:3467/Exceptions?exdate=20090108
```

However, when I publish it to our dev server at `\\deverserver\apps\MyProject`, note the duplication in the URL for the same link:

```
http://devserver/apps/MyProject/MyProject/Exceptions?exdate=20090108
```

Any idea what's going on?

Note: These links are all built via `Html.ActionLink()`.

Update: I can duplicate this locally if I specify a Specific Port and Virtual Path in My Project | Web | Use Visual Studio Development Server:

- Specific Port: 1234
- Virtual Path: /apps/MyProject
- Resulting URL: `http://localhost:1234/apps/MyProject/MyProject/Exceptions?exdate=20090108`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you performed all the steps [(here)](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) to deploy the MVC app in the IIS6?

Comment: That turned out to be the problem. It took me a while to figure out it was an IIS6 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the IIS folder set as an application? It should have a cog icon in the IIS explorer.

Comment: What he said, except more specifically: is it the Apps folder that has the cog, or the MyProject folder that has the cog? Unless you're doing something unusual with Routing, this is an IIS setup issue.

Comment: Yes, the MyProject folder has the cog. Note my update to the original question - I can reproduce it locally, so I'm assuming it's something in my project set specific to MVC (never seen this problem with regular ASP.NET.

Comment: Ok, I'm tapping out, good luck :) It's also possible that there's a bug in Html.ActionLink as I'm pretty sure ~everyone else deploys their MVC apps to the IIS root folder. Last thing to check: your Routing setup, I don't know what to look for though.

Comment: Is this a side-effect of running on IIS6?